Issue with flutterfire configure, says it ran into an error when running the command firebase projects:create web-app-personal --json
I just added flutterfire to my zsh path, I'm using the terminal inside android studio if that helps. I'm trying to configure a web app to use firebase and ran into an issue with flutterfire configure.
When I run flutterfire configure everything is fine until it tries to run this command:
firebase projects:create web-app-personal --json

I updated my flutterfire and googled issues with json, but I think I'm looking in the wrong places to solve this issue.
